# Embedding snake game to engage website visitors , while page/module gets loaded in website

Tags: javascript, html

In my website there are different flex and HTML modules , which takes some time to load . During that time viewers have no choice instead looking at throbber/loader gif image & waiting that page/module to be loaded up fully.

I want to engage viewers during that time by giving them an option of playing snake game or any other thing which can be timepass activity.

If anyone of you have any idea regarding that , can you please suggest me how to implement it ?

Comment: won't the game make the page size grow even more?

Comment: Yeah may be , but at this point , I don't bother about page size and all . I just want to engage them & want to see if it can really entertain viewers or not

Comment: We achieved this by copy-pasting snake game js and aligning it with angular js framework . Our idea was to  display snake game instead of loader , but we couldn't achieve that , hence satisfied by adding snake game (silo) on error page only (Kind of google chrome's 'No Internet Connection Error Page' dragon game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire code for a vanilla snake game is available [here](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/html5-game-tutorial-make-a-snake-game-using-html5-canvas-jquery), please add it to your front-end code.

The idea would be to put this in a div with the same background color as the throbber on the loading page. Load it when page loading starts and to hide (or destroy) the div completely when page loading is complete.

The hard part is seamlessly getting a snake from a throbber (like YouTube does). Hey but even if you load the snake game from the start, it is a good start.

Comment: Thanks @dhwaneet Bhatt . Will check it out and you know the progress